# Check that first word of each line contains specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

When validating user input, I'm using a regular expression to check that at the beginning of each line (that actually contains content, double spaces are skipped), there is always a set of parenthesis with content within before any other characters.  After fiddling around with multiple variations, here's the most simplistic version I came up with that is failing

```
var regex = new RegExp('^\\([^)]+\\).*?$', 'm');
```

The intended result is to test true against instances such as:

> (test) whatever.\n(another test) again... whatever

or

> (test) whatever.\n\n(another test) again... whatever

If any line in the string does begin with a `(`, have at least one character within the parenthesis, and is then closed by `)` before having any amount of content after the parenthesis, it should fail; alas, my expression above will ignore any attempt at checking any line past the first.  If I have a malformed second line such as `(test) whatever\nthis) should return false`, it still returns true on a `.test()`.

Some valid matches might include:

> (test) pass
>
> (test) pass\n(also) passes
>
> (again) pass\n\n(also) pass\n(we) can do this all day
>
> (There) can\n(be) any\n\n(amount) of \n(newlines) as\n\n\n\n(long) as each \n(line) that has \n(content) starts \n(with a) set of parenthesis.
>
> (The) types\n\n(of) characters\n(don't) matter,\n(with) the only\n(exception) being the \n(strict enforcement) of the\n(open and close parenthesis) at the beginning of each line

Some invalid matches that should return false on a `.test()` include:

> Nope
>
> Also Nope
>
> (No closing parenthesis = Nope
>
> Nope for the opposite of above)
>
> (Yep so far) actually....\nNope
>
> Big bowl of\n(Nope!)
>
> ) Take a guess?
>
> () No good

Comment: Maybe `/^(?:\([^)]+\).*[\r\n]*)+$/`? Or [`/^\([^)]+\).*(?:[\r\n]+\([^)]+\).*)*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/cP4zW7/1). I suggest using a literal regex notation.

Comment: Or do you mean [`^(?!\([^)]+\)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/cP4zW7/2)?

Comment: added some pass/fail examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate every line starts with `(...)` in a multiline text you can use this regex:

```
/^(?:\(.+?\).*[\r\n]*)+$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY4hA3/2)

This will fail the match if any line start doesn't have `(...)` pattern.

Comment: Another option is to use [`!/^(?!\([^)\n]+\)|\s*$)/m.test(input)`](https://regex101.com/r/vY4hA3/3) **(Note use of negation at the start)**

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
var regex = /^(?:(?:^|\r*\n)(?:[\t ]*|\s*\([\t ]*(?:[^\(\)\s][\t ]*)+\)[^\r\n]*))*$/;
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Test it live on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LgZJiqmglnPVnuVH)